# when click to add to cart button , product details is not showing up in shoping cart page

Tags: checkout, addtocart

I am facing problem here with my magento site . When i click on add to cart button and add any product first time i am not able to see details of the product like product name , Unit price , Qty, subtotal but i am getting MSG "product was added to your shopping cart."and able to see the grand total for that product . but when i add any other or same product second time i am able to see all the details .

Can any one help me to debug this issue . [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is `tr.first.odd` property display is none

In file `skin/frontend/default/abprinting/css/theme.css` at line 5993

```
tr.first.odd {
    display: none;
}
```

changed it to:

```
tr.first.odd {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhh...... I did not notice it ... Thanks Arunendra... :)

Comment: If it helps to you can mark as accepted.